# To print only alphabets and display error for digits or special character strings

Tags: c

I'm unable to print error when input is only special characters or digits string. It works with mixed string but not for digit or special character string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

    void main()
    {
        int c = 0, i;
        char s[20];char*r;
        printf("Enter the string:\n");
        fgets(s,20,stdin);
        for (i = 0;i < sizeof(s); i++)
        {
            if( (s[i]<'A' || s[i]>'Z') || (s[i]<'a' || s[i]>'z'))
                c++;
        }
        if( (c == (strlen(s)) || (c == strlen(s)-1)))
            printf("No alphabets to display");
        else
        {
            for(r = s; *r; *r++)
            {
                if(isalpha(*r)) 
                    printf("%c",*r);
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: `void main()`...hmm..time to update your book.

Comment: What error? Where did you try to print?

Comment: You clearly know about `isalpha`, why don't you use it in the first loop (using it like `!isalpha(s[i])`)? I also recommend you remove the ending newline first, then count the number of alphabetic characters. If the count is less than the length of the string it contains non-alphabetic characters. If the count is zero then the string contain *no* alphabetic characters.

Comment: You also have a logical error in the first loop, where you loop over `sizeof s` characters, which will go into uninitialized data if the user didn't enter an 18 or 19 character string for input. You should use `strlen` here.

Comment: `i<sizeof(s)` --> `s[i]`

Comment: `if((s[i]<'A' || s[i]>'Z') || (s[i]<'a' || s[i]>'z'))` --> `if(!(s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z' || s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z'))` or just `if(!isalpha((unsigned char)s[i]))`

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/9zKK1S)

Answer (score 0):

Add this fragment to your code :
`else if(!isalpha(*s))
printf("No alphabets to display");`

And correct your code : `for(i=0;i<sizeof(s);i++)`
to : `for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)`